# What does "scooping in" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In Greyhound (2020), Eagle gives her ship status report:

> We have a five-degree list at starboard, and we're down at the stern,
> but we'll tow all right up to five knots. We have a flap of plate
> sticking up, **scooping in** the sea. The list gets worse if we make any
> speed.

What does "scooping in" mean? I know "scoop up" means but "scoop in" is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably a section of the outer hull has opened up leaving a forward-facing hole, so that as the ship moves, water is actively channelled into her. As the scooping action is sideways and not upwards, *scooping up* would not be appropriate.